# How do I convert a working XSL 2.0 DateTime conversion to xsl 1.0

Tags: xslt, datetime

I am trying to get my equivalent XSL 2.0 Datetime function conversion I have that works retrofitted to 1.0.

I need to just add 1 day to an existing datetime element and hunting about for xsl 2 I found this and it works like a dream.

```
<xsl:template match="StartDateTime">
<StartDateTime>
  <xsl:value-of select="xsd:dateTime(.) + xsd:dayTimeDuration'P1D')"/>
</StartDateTime>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="EndDateTime">
<EndDateTime>
  <xsl:value-of select="xsd:dateTime(.) + xsd:dayTimeDuration'P1D')"/>
</EndDateTime>
</xsl:template>
```

Problem is the transformer I put it into doesn't like advanced functions from xsl 2 and I am struggling to find something simple for xsl 1.0

Any help greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance Andy

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the XSLT processor you are using supports the EXSLT extension function library. Alternatively, at www.exslt.org you will find some portable implementations of date/time functions provided in the form of named templates.

Comment: Thanks Michael I eventually had to find a very verbose way of getting this done using raw XSLT and defining every possible date time piece like month, day, year etc.